# When I click QPushButton, I want to change QTextBrowser's text

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qtextbrowser

My Code has 2 problems.

1. I want QPushButton is upper than QTextBrowser.

- But, I can't. You can check image. [image].

2. When I click QPushButton, I want to change QTextBrowser's Text.

- But, I has an error.
  -> Error message: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'text_area'

This is my code.
I think I don't have Python programming process.

```
# test.py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QTextBrowser

class MyApp(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        btn2 = QPushButton(self)
        btn2.setText('Button&2')
        btn2.setGeometry(20,20,100,100)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.callme)

        # Add QTextBrowser
        text_area = QTextBrowser(self)
        text_area.setGeometry(120, 160, 270, 120)
        text_area.setText('Before Edit')

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(btn2)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle('QPushButton')
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 500, 600)
        self.show()

    def callme(self):
        self.text_area.setText('After Edit')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the problem is that you used `text_edit` at the top, but `self.text_edit` at the bottom. Then, to put the button at the top, set the vbox alignment to the top using `vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)`

Try this:

```python
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QTextBrowser

class MyApp(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        btn2 = QPushButton(self)
        btn2.setText('Button&2')
        btn2.setGeometry(20,20,100,100)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.callme)

        # Add QTextBrowser
        self.text_area = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.text_area.setGeometry(120, 160, 270, 120)
        self.text_area.setText('Before Edit')

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(btn2)
        vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle('QPushButton')
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 500, 600)
        self.show()

    def callme(self):
        self.text_area.setText('After Edit')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```